# Eclipse maven to manage only dependencies and nothing more

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, maven, dependency-management

Is it possible for maven plugin to manage only dependencies and nothing more.

I work with "strange" maven project, and want Eclipse/maven plugin only to read dependencies from pom.xml and add it to project classpath. And nothing more.

I don't want it to set exclusion filters, source folders and output folders, or to overwrite other dependencies.

Also, pom.xml is not located in the source folder of Eclipse project. I know I could use mvn eclipse:eclipse task manually, but it mess with my .classpath and .project files, which I don't want to merge manually.

To summary, I want that all dependencies from pom.xml are automatically managed by plugin, but for plugin not to touch anything else.

EDIT: The problem is that whenever something in pom.xml changes, maven plugin changes my project configuration.

EDIT: It has to be maven since there is already pom.xml which I can replace with sbt or ivy or lein or anything eles.

Comment: That should be possible if you disable automatic builds and just don't configure the rest. Where did you have problems?

Comment: @Thomas, my experience with trying to use m2e along with scala-ide was really bad.  Basically the scala ide stops working completely, even if you turn off the maven project builder.  I wanted to use m2e only for dependency management, exactly like this question, and I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be maven? If you don't need any of the plugins, or project organisation you could use [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a even more simple one like [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki)

if you have to use maven, just strip out the plugins from the pom.xml file and only add the dependencies and repos and use an IDE to launch the aplication or create a jar.

you will need to run mvn commands thought if you change the dependencies.